# Поиск подматрицы

Tags: javascript

Матрицу A мы назавем "десятичной ", если после удаления  каждой строки и столбца i, в полученной подматрице сумма элементов больше или равно 10 -и.

Например

```
A = [
      [2, 4, 6],
      [2, 2, 2], 
      [4, 8, 8]
]
```

Нужно написать функцию которая получает матрицу и возвращает true если она "десятичная " и false в обратном случае.

```
    function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (matrix[j][i] === 0) {
                break;
            }
            res += matrix[j][i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

function solution(a) {
    let res = 0;
    if (matrixElementsSum(a) > 10) {
        res = true;
    } else {
        res = false;
    }
    return res
}

console.log(decimalSubMatrix([[2, 4, 6],[2, 2, 2],[4, 8, 8]]))   //  true           
console.log(decimalSubMatrix([[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 2, 1]]))    //  false               
console.log(decimalSubMatrix([[4, 6, 8, 1],[2, 3, 5, 6],[1, 2, 8, 1], [9, 1, 0, 3]]))  // true
console.log(decimalSubMatrix([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]))  //  false                 

console.log(decimalSubMatrix([[1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1]])) // true но должен возврощать false
```

Поможете решить задачу?

Comment: Поможем, если вы покажите вашу самую лучшую попытку :)

Comment: function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (matrix[j][i] === 0) {
                break;
            }
            res += matrix[j][i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

function decimalSubMatrix(a) {
    let res = 0;
    if (matrixElementsSum(a) > 10) {
        res = true;
    } else {
  res = false;
 }
 return res
}

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, пожалуйста. Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1103326/edit). Так же опишите, в чем именно у вас проблема.

Comment: Здесь мне видится ошибка `matrix[0].length`. Или они у вас всегда "квадратные" будут? Для чего служит условие `if (matrix[j][i] === 0) {
                break;
            }`?

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу это вот, так, могу расписать поподробнее, если что-то непонятно будет.

```js
const exampleArr1 = [
  [2, 4, 6],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [4, 8, 8],
];
const exampleArr2 = [
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1]
];
const exampleArr3 = [
  [4, 6, 8, 1],
  [2, 3, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 8, 1],
  [9, 1, 0, 3]
];
const exampleArr4 = [
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 2, 1]
];
function toPrematrix(array, index) {
  // преобразовываем к подматрице
  // принимает первым аргументом массив и индекс строки и столбцы который нужно убрать
  const returnarr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (i !== index) {
      const preArr = [];
      if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j += 1) {
          if (j !== index) {
            preArr.push(array[i][j]);
          }
        }
      }
      returnarr.push(preArr);
    }
  }
  return returnarr;
}
const isMoreThanTenMatrix = (matrix) => {
  // передаем получившуюся подматрицу и её анализируем
  const toOneLevelArray = (arr) => arr.reduce((accum, currentVal) => accum.concat(Array.isArray(currentVal) ? toOneLevelArray(currentVal) : currentVal), []);
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
  const oneLevelArr = toOneLevelArray(matrix);
  const summOfelements = oneLevelArr.reduce(reducer);
  if (summOfelements >= 10) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
console.log(isMoreThanTenMatrix(toPrematrix(exampleArr1, 0)));
console.log(isMoreThanTenMatrix(toPrematrix(exampleArr2, 0)));
console.log(isMoreThanTenMatrix(toPrematrix(exampleArr3, 0)));
console.log(isMoreThanTenMatrix(toPrematrix(exampleArr4, 0)));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо Евгений но к сожелению в случае const exampleArr4 = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 1]
];

возврощает true но должен возврощать false

Comment: Возвращает false, добавил этот массив в пример

Comment: Да извините вы правы

Comment: Если вас устраивает мой ответ, буду рад и благодарен его принятию.