# Равенство анаграмм

Tags: javascript

Мы скажем что  в десятичной системе две числа a, b  являются анаграммами друг для друга, если в двоичной  системе  их цифры в позиции i  те же самые.
Например 
в случае если a = 8, b = 4 в двоичной системе получим a = 1000, b = 100, мы видим что в обоих случаях применялись  те же самые цифры. И следовательно a, b  являются анаграммами друг для друга. А в случае a = 45, b = 10 получим a = 101101, b = 1010, которые не являются анаграммами друг для друга.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно написать функцию которая получает массив [a, b] и возвращает true если a, b  являются анаграммами друг для друга и false в обратном случае.

```js
function areAnagramm(x) {
  let a = x[0];
  let b = x[1];

  let i = 0;
  let binary_a = [];

  let j = 0;
  let binary_b = [];

  while (a > 0) {
    binary_a[i] = a % 2;
    a /= 2;
    i++;
  }

  while (b > 0) {
    binary_b[j] = b % 2;
    b /= 2;
    j++;
  }

  binary_a.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  binary_b.sort((a, b) => b - a);

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (binary_a[i] != binary_b[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(areAnagramm([8, 4])); // true
console.log(areAnagramm([45, 10])); // false
```

Поможете написать более оптимальный вариант?

Comment: Слева от ответа - знак "галочка". Он сделан для Вас. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1103326/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b

Answer (score 2):

Формулировка задача ужасная. Это что, автоматический перевод?

Вам не нужны никакие массивы, a тем более - их сортировка и поэлементное сравнение. Просто посчитайте количество единиц.

```js
function areAnagramm(x) {
  let i = countOnes(x[0]);
  let j = countOnes(x[1]);
  return i == j;

  function countOnes(a) {
    let i = 0;
    while (a > 0) {
      if (a % 2)
        i++;
      a /= 2;
    }
    return i;
  }
}
console.log(areAnagramm([8, 4])); // true
console.log(areAnagramm([45, 10])); // false
```